# Multi-path application with path based routing in Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I want to run a spring boot application over ingress having multiple path Like

```
http://localhost:8888/login
http://localhost:8888/client/dev
```

On localhost when i run this application it automatically redirect to /login

I am using traefik ingress controller. The pod and service is running. Ingress configured as below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-entry-point: https
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: config
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: config.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: config
            port:
              number: 8888
        path: /config
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

when i open https://config.example.com/config  it redirects to https://config.example.com/login and i get 404 error.

What annotations can be used so that it allow me to do further sub path routing.

Comment: Which version of Traefik are you using? Current `apiVersion` should be `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`. Also, according to your yaml you `/config` should redirect to root `/`, re you sure your application doesn't do redirection?

Comment: I am using traefik:v1.7. I tried using "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1". But getting error "unknown field "service" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1beta1.IngressBackend"... application redirects to /login (as per application nature) but i get 404 not found because ingress search for application mapped to /login. It should be like  https://config.example.com/config/login

Comment: As far as I'm aware proper keys should be `serviceName` and `servicePort`, so like this:
`- backend:
     serviceName: config
     servicePort: 8888`